# Read a local file in django

Tags: python, django, path

I'm quite stuck on this one! 
I am writing a Django view that reads data from an external database. To do this, I am using the standard MySQLdb library.
Now, to load the data, I must do a very long and complex query. I can hard code that query in my view and that works just fine.
But I think that is not practical; I want to be able to change the query in the future, so I try to load the statement from a text file. 
My problem is that I don't know where to store and how to open that file. Wherever I do, I get a "No such file or directory" error. Even saving it in the same directory than the code of the view fails.

Note that this is not an uploaded file; it's just an external file that completes my code.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, actually I had tried to put it in the same direcotry as the code of the view and normal open() function. As it had failed, I tried to find some information, but all I tried failed (IE: putting it in a "static" subdirectory of my app). An absolute path would work, but I still wanted more flexibility

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Keep the file in django project root and add the following in the settings.py file.

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Then in the view do this.

```
import os
from django.conf.settings import PROJECT_ROOT

file_ = open(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'filename'))
```

Update:

In newer Django versions `BASE_DIR` is already defined in the settings.py file. So you can do the following.

```
import os
from django.conf import settings

file_ = open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'filename'))
```

Comment: A small update that takes into account latest version of Django.
`from django.conf import settings`
`file_ = open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'filename'))`

Comment: ... and what do you mean by 'newer or latest' version? `django 3.1`?

Answer (score 5):

For this use, I'd put it in the settings module. In `settings.py`, add e.g. `MY_LONG_QUERY = 'from FOO select BAR...'`. Then, in your view just load it from the settings like so:

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.MY_LONG_QUERY
```

But, this doesn't really answer your question. Assuming permissions and all are correct, keep a reference to your project root in your settings like this:

```
ROOT_PATH = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0]
```

And then again in your view, open your file like so:

```
from django.conf import settings

def read_from_database(request):
    f = open(os.path.join(settings.ROOT_PATH, 'myfile.db'))
    # Do something with f
```

Comment: After the previous answer, that's just what I did hehe. But I also like the idea of saving the query in settings.py!