# Reading a static file

Tags: django

I have a Django project called `myproject`, which has an app called `myapp`. I want to read a text file and load its contents into a list. I'm a little confused about static files and relative directories in Django, and my initial attempt is not working. So far, I have the following code...

In `/myproject/settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In `/myapp/static/myapp`, there is a file called `myfile.txt`.

In `/myapp/views.py`:

```
with open('myapp/myfile.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

When running the server, I get the error: `No such file or directory: 'myapp/myfile.txt'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13067290/263989

Comment: Did you try `myapp/static/myapp/myfile.txt` instead of `myapp/myfile.txt` ?

Answer (score 1):

in your settings:

```
import os
gettext = lambda s: s
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '..'))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "media")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

create a folder `media` under your app folder.

then put the file you want to read in that folder.

and try this in your views.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
with open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '\\yourfile.text', 'rb') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
```

Comment: Use os.path.join instead of + '\\'.